# Sliding groups in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set which contains a number of unique identifiers for each date, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-02")), 
ids = c(3, 4, 1, 3))
```

I'd then like to summarise this information to get the number of new unique ids that appear on the current date.  For example, on January 1 there are two uniques ids (3 and 4).  But on January 2, there is only one new unique id (1).  So the resulting data frame should look like:

```
date          n_new_unique_ids
2016-01-01                   2
2016-01-02                   1
```

Is this possible with `dplyr`?  I had a look at `lag` but a fixed lag size doesn't make sense in this context.  Or perhaps with another package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to remove all the `duplicated` 'ids' from the dataset

```
df %>%
  filter(!(duplicated(ids)|duplicated(ids, fromLast=TRUE)))
#        date ids
#1 2016-01-01   2
#2 2016-01-02   3
```

#### Update

Using the updated data

```
df %>%
    arrange(date, ids) %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(ids)) %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(n_unique_ids = n())
 #       date n_unique_ids
 #      <date>        <int>
 #1 2016-01-01            2
 #2 2016-01-02            1
```

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @jkeirstead  I updated the post, perhaps that helps

Comment: Using `distinct(ids, .keep_all = TRUE)` should be much faster than `filter(!duplicated(ids))`.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `aggregate`. We can keep only those rows which has unique id's and then find it's `length`.

```
aggregate(ids~date, df[!duplicated(df$ids),], length)

#     date     ids
#1 2016-01-01   2
#2 2016-01-02   1
```